# Cannot read property '_idleNext' of undefined

Tags: node.js, server-push

I've made a pushlet for HTML5 EventSource object in node.js. I'm using version 0.4.8 on linux. It sometimes works ok, but sometimes it will crash with the following error:

```
_linklist.js:65
  item._idleNext = list._idleNext;

TypeError: Cannot read property '_idleNext' of undefined
    at Object.append (_linklist.js:65:24)
    at Object.active (timers.js:136:9)
    at Socket._writeOut (net.js:461:10)
    at Socket.write (net.js:378:17)
    at ServerResponse.end (http.js:671:29)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> ([my pushlet url]:88:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:61:17)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1018:22)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:684:27)
```

When it crashes, it crashes on the first request it receives. If it doesn't, it works well with all requests in close future. I've notices that when I open the base url on which my nodeJS pushlet responds after starting it, it never crashes and keeps working well for subsequent requests. Either way, whenever it works, if left idle for a long time it has a good chance of crashing when it receives the next request.

Anyone have an idea about what's wrong here? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug that we can expect to be fixed in future versions?

Comment: You need to post code samples for the code that sets up both the `item` and `list` variables.  My guess is in your setup code, you are using async functions that haven't completed by the time the first request comes in, but no one can give anything other than a generic "your code that establishes either item or list is broken" answer unless you post the relevant code.  Async stack traces have the issue of often not including the code where the actual bug is.  Chances of this being a bug inside node.js as opposed to your code are quite slim.

Comment: Peter, item and list are both variables in _linklist.js which is a part of nodejs. It contains the code that manages a simple linked list and I don't think it is exposed to the user of nodejs. It is my guess that timers.js has a problem with a linked list when it is empty or something like that.

Comment: The entire stack trace is node libraries. Post a code sample reproducing the problem.  How else do you expect folks to debug this for you?  We can't tell you if you are "doing something wrong" because you haven't told us what you are doing in code.  Code talks. Paragraphs describing code walk.

Comment: I've made a gist with the whole script for my request for help on the mailing list. Here's the link for your StackOverflowers as well: https://gist.github.com/0ec8b5581bdbf80fb433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the version 0.4.9 has solved my problem.